# How to declare css fallback from max(env(safe-area-inset-bottom))

Tags: css

I have this bit of css:

```css
  transform: translateY(50px);
  transform: translateY(max(50px, env(safe-area-inset-bottom)));
```

My expectation is that browsers that do not support `max()`, would fall back to `transform: translateY(50px)`

However, that doesn't seem to be the case with neither Chrome nor Firefox.

https://jsbin.com/xozexin/7/edit?html,css,output

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is not really how  CSS Fallbacks work.
Take the following snippet for example :

```css
.some-selector {
    width: 200px;
    width: max(50px , 200px);
}
```

Because `max` is not a valid CSS function (not supported by the browser), browsers don’t change and replace the width value but keep the `200px` value for the width property.

In your case `translateY` is a valid function but you just passed invalid value.

As an alternative you can use [CSS @supports](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/@supports)

```css
div {
  width:250px;
  height:200px;
  background: green;
  transform: translateY(50px);
}


@supports (width: max(5px,5px)) {
   div {
     transform: translateY(max(50px, env(safe-area-inset-bottom))) !important;
   }
}
```

I have tested with JavaScript

```js
console.log(CSS.supports("width", "max(5px,10px)"))
console.log(CSS.supports("transform","translateY(max(50px, env(safe-area-inset-bottom)))"))
```

Comment: Not sure I understand.. Can you demonstrate how to solve the problem in the question?

Comment: Yeah.. no.. I [tried it here](https://jsbin.com/xozexin/8/edit?html,css,output), doesn't work. Chrome still thinks it's supported.

Comment: @Birowsky how about changing the condition to `width: max(5px,5px)`

Comment: This now is a workaround, but an acceptable one. Thanx. Here's the shortest version that works for me: `@supports (margin: max(0)) {..}`